# Landscape table to fit entire page by automatic line breaks

Tags: tables, line-breaking, landscape, pdflscape

I want to include a large table into my document. I use the landscape environment to make it sideways and managed to make it fill out the entire width of the page by using \linewidth, but my table doesn't fill the entire height of the page, so the fontsize is very small and hardly readable. In order to change it I thought about including automatic linebreaks with tabularx but couldn't figure out how to do so. Any ideas on how I can have my table fill the entire page?

This is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \caption{Übersicht gängiger Bodenerosionsmodelle }
            \begin{adjustbox}{width=\linewidth}
                \begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c}
                    \thead{Modell}&\thead{Modelltyp}&\thead{Anwendungsbereich}&\thead{Zeitliche Auflösung}&\thead{modellierte Erosionsform}&\thead{Anmerkungen}\\
                    \hline
                    \thead{Allgemeine Bodenabtragsgleichung (ABAG)}&empirisch&Hang/kleine landwirtschaftliche EZG& jährlicher Mittelwert&Anpassung der USLE für den mitteleuropäischen Raum\\
                    \hline
                    \thead{Agricultural Non-Point \\Source Model\\(AGNPS)}&konzeptionell&landwirtschaftliche EZG bis 20.000ha&ereignisbezogen&Flächen-, Rillen-, Grabenerosion&Fokus auf der Modellierung von Nähr- und Schadstoffen\\
                    \hline
                    \thead{Areal Non-point Source\\ Watershed Environment \\Response Simulation\\(ANSWERS)}&physikalisch&landwirtschaftliche EZG bis 10000 ha&ursprünglich ereignisbezogen, mittlerweile auch kontinuierliche Simulation&Flächen- Rillen-, später auch Grabenerosion&erstes physikalisches Modell, dass auf einem Raster beruht\\
                    \hline
                    \thead{Chemicals, Runoff and \\Erosion from Agricultural\\ Management Systems\\(CREAMS)}&physikalisch&feldgroßes EZG, 40-400 ha&täglich oder ereignisbezogen& Grabenerosion und -deposition&verwendet statt eines Rasters ein Diskretisierungsverfahren, mit dem homogene Elemente festgelegt werden\\
                    \hline
                    \thead{Limburg Soil Erosion Model\\(LISEM)}&physikalisch&Hang/kleines EZG&ereignisbezogen&simuliert keine Erosionstypen sondern den Abtrag durch Wasseransammlungen&räumliche Verteilung des Outputs wird als Karte ausgegeben\\
                    \hline
                    \thead{Productivity, Erosion and Runoff,\\ Functions to Evaluate Conservation Techniques \\(PERFECT)}&physikalisch&blablabla&blablabla&blablabla&blablabla\\
                    \hline
                    \thead{Universal Soil Loss Equation\\(USLE)}&empirisch&Hang/kleine landwirtschaftliche EZG&jährlicher Mittelwert&Rillen- und Flächenerosion&beruht auf langährigen Messreihen aus der USA, Basis für viele weitere Modelle\\
                    \hline
                    \thead{Water Erosion Prediction Project (WEPP)}&physikalisch&Module für Hang/EZG&ereignisbezogen, monatlich&Flächen-, Rillen-,Grabenerosion&verschiedene Version auch für Wald- und Straßenbau\\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{adjustbox}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5):

(added `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}` wrappers for material in column 1, added code to suppress an inappropriate f-l ligature in the word "Auflösung", uploaded a better screenshot)

I would like to suggest that you employ a `tabularx` environment, with a target width of `\linewidth` and automatic line breaking enabled for five of the six columns of the table. And, do place the `tabularx` environment inside a `sidewaystable` environment to switch to landscape format.

And, to give the table a more open "look", I'd get rid of all vertical rules and employ fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horiz. rules
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % no full justification
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\hyphenation{graben-ero-sion flächen-ero-sion 
  creams answers ero-sions-typen 
  boden-abtrags-glei-chung ereignis-bezogen}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\small % 10% linear reduction in font size 
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Übersicht gängiger Bodenerosionsmodelle}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L l LLLL @{}}
   \toprule
   % suppress f-l ligature in "Auflösung" ...
   Modell & Modelltyp & Anwendungsbereich & Zeitliche Auf\kern0.03em lösung & Modellierte Erosionsform & Anmerkungen \\
   \midrule

   Allgemeine Bodenabtragsgleichung (ABAG) & 
   empirisch & Hang\slash kleine landwirtschaftliche EZG & jährlicher Mittelwert & Anpassung der USLE für den mitteleuropäischen Raum \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Agricultural Non-Point Source Model} (AGNPS) & 
   konzeptionell & landwirtschaftliche EZG bis 20.000~ha & ereignisbezogen & Flächen-, Rillen-, Grabenerosion & Fokus auf der Modellierung von Nähr- und Schadstoffen \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Areal Non-point Source Watershed Environment Response Simulation} (ANSWERS) & 
   physikalisch & landwirtschaftliche EZG bis 10.000~ha & ursprünglich ereignisbezogen, mittlerweile auch kontinuierliche Simulation & Flächen- Rillen-, später auch Grabenerosion & erstes physikalisches Modell, dass auf einem Raster beruht \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Chemicals, Runoff and Erosion from Agricultural Management Systems} (CREAMS) & 
   physikalisch & feldgroßes EZG, 40--400 ha & täglich oder ereignisbezogen &  Grabenerosion und \mbox{-deposition} & verwendet statt eines Rasters ein Diskretisierungsverfahren, mit dem homogene Elemente festgelegt werden \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Limburg Soil Erosion Model} (LISEM) & 
   physikalisch & Hang\slash kleines EZG & ereignisbezogen & simuliert keine Erosionstypen sondern den Abtrag durch Wasseransammlungen & räumliche Verteilung des Outputs wird als Karte ausgegeben \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Productivity, Erosion and Runoff, Functions to Evaluate Conservation Techniques} (PERFECT) & 
   physikalisch & blablabla & blablabla & blablabla & blablabla \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Universal Soil Loss Equation} (USLE) & 
   empirisch & Hang\slash kleine landwirtschaftliche EZG & jährlicher Mittelwert & Rillen- und Flächenerosion & beruht auf langjährigen Messreihen aus den USA, Basis für viele weitere Modelle \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Water Erosion Prediction Project} (WEPP) & 
   physikalisch & Module für Hang\slash EZG & ereignisbezogen, monatlich & Flächen-, Rillen-, Grabenerosion & verschiedene Version auch für Wald- und Straßenbau\\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why sidewaystable instead of pdflscape?  Are you trying to avoid the immediate \clearpage?

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Speaking for myself (who else?!), I find `\begin{sidewaystable} ... \end{sidewaystable}` quite a bit simpler than `\begin{landscape}\begin{table} ... \end{table}\end{landscape}`. Also, the `rotating` package, which provides the `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure` environments, does a very good job of switching the meaning of the parameters `\textheight` and `\textwidth` transparently. This, in turns, makes setting the target width of the `tabularx` environment in landscape-mode a no-brainer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me! And I also adopted your open table look to all of my tables, they look much beetre now :)

Comment: @Idiza - You're most welcome!

Answer (score 4):

- It seems, that your table is to big that can be fit on one page, so I suggest to use some kind of long table and `landscape` environment.
- For automatic breaking text in cells into several lines you need to prescribe columns widths. This can be simple done with use of `X` column type as defined for example in `tabularx` or in `tabularray` packages.
- With `tabularray` package MWE can be as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}    
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\hyphenation{graben-ero-sion flächen-ero-sion creams answers ero-sions-typen}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Übersicht gängiger Bodenerosionsmodelle},
  label = {tab:?}
                ]{colsep=3pt,
                  colspec = {@{} X[cmd=\RaggedRight] l *{4}{X[cmd=\RaggedRight]} @{}},
                  cells = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont},
                  %rowsep = 3pt,
                  row{1} = {c, m},
                  rowhead=1
                 }

   \toprule
Modell  &   Modelltyp 
            &   Anwendungsbereich 
                &   Zeitliche Auflösung 
                    &   Modellierte Erosionsform 
                        &   Anmerkungen                 \\
   \midrule
Allgemeine Bodenabtragsgleichung (ABAG) 
        &   empirisch & Hang\slash kleine landwirtschaftliche EZG 
            &   jährlicher Mittelwert 
                &   Anpassung der USLE für den mitteleuropäischen Raum 
                    &   &                               \\
Agricultural Non-Point Source Model (AGNPS) 
        &   konzeptionell
            &   landwirtschaftliche EZG bis \qty{20000}{\hectare} 
                &   ereignisbezogen 
                    &   Flächen-, Rillen-, Grabenerosion 
                        & Fokus auf der Modellierung von Nähr- und Schadstoffen \\
 Areal Non-point Source Watershed Environment Response Simulation (ANSWERS) 
        &   physikalisch & landwirtschaftliche EZG bis \qty{1000}{\hectare} ha 
            &   ursprünglich ereignisbezogen, mittlerweile auch kontinuierliche Simulation 
                &   Flächen- Rillen-, später auch Grabenerosion 
                    &   erstes physikalisches Modell, dass auf einem Raster beruht \\
Chemicals, Runoff and Erosion from Agricultural Management Systems (CREAMS) & physikalisch 
        &   feldgroßes EZG, \qtyrange{40}{400}{\hectare} 
            &   täglich oder ereignisbezogen 
                &  Grabenerosion und -deposition 
                    &   verwendet statt eines Rasters ein Diskretisierungsverfahren, mit dem homogene Elemente festgelegt werden \\
Limburg Soil Erosion Model (LISEM) 
        &   physikalisch 
            &   Hang\slash kleines EZG & ereignisbezogen 
                &   simuliert keine Erosionstypen sondern den Abtrag durch Wasseransammlungen 
                    &   räumliche Verteilung des Outputs wird als Karte ausgegeben \\
Productivity, Erosion and Runoff, Functions to Evaluate Conservation Techniques (PERFECT) 
        &   physikalisch
            &   blablabla
                &   blablabla
                    &   blablabla
                        &   blablabla       \\
Universal Soil Loss Equation (USLE) 
        &   empirisch & Hang\slash kleine landwirtschaftliche EZG 
            &   jährlicher Mittelwert & Rillen- und Flächenerosion 
                &   beruht auf langährigen Messreihen aus den USA, Basis für viele weitere Modelle
                    &   &                   \\
Water Erosion Prediction Project (WEPP) 
        &   physikalisch & Module für Hang\slash EZG & ereignisbezogen, monatlich 
            &   Flächen-, Rillen-, Grabenerosion & verschiedene Version auch für Wald- und Straßenbau
                &   &   &                   \\
   \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to add the acronyms USLE and PERFECT to the list of arguments of `\hyphenation`.

Comment: @Mico, Thank very much. I'm not sure if acronyms can be hyphenated. In my native language this happens only in rare exceptions.. I will left this to OP ;-).

Answer (score 3):

This is basically Mico's answer with a few additions.  The idea is to use the hook from floatpag to rotate the page/view.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horiz. rules
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % no full justification
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\hyphenation{graben-ero-sion flächen-ero-sion 
  creams answers ero-sions-typen 
  boden-abtrags-glei-chung ereignis-bezogen}
  
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rotateview}{\global\@namedef{\number\@currbox @float}{\PLS@AddRotate{-90}%
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{\PLS@RemoveRotate}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\rotateview
\small % 10% linear reduction in font size 
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Übersicht gängiger Bodenerosionsmodelle}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L l LLLL @{}}
   \toprule
   % suppress f-l ligature in "Auflösung" ...
   Modell & Modelltyp & Anwendungsbereich & Zeitliche Auf\kern0.03em lösung & Modellierte Erosionsform & Anmerkungen \\
   \midrule

   Allgemeine Bodenabtragsgleichung (ABAG) & 
   empirisch & Hang\slash kleine landwirtschaftliche EZG & jährlicher Mittelwert & Anpassung der USLE für den mitteleuropäischen Raum \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Agricultural Non-Point Source Model} (AGNPS) & 
   konzeptionell & landwirtschaftliche EZG bis 20.000~ha & ereignisbezogen & Flächen-, Rillen-, Grabenerosion & Fokus auf der Modellierung von Nähr- und Schadstoffen \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Areal Non-point Source Watershed Environment Response Simulation} (ANSWERS) & 
   physikalisch & landwirtschaftliche EZG bis 10.000~ha & ursprünglich ereignisbezogen, mittlerweile auch kontinuierliche Simulation & Flächen- Rillen-, später auch Grabenerosion & erstes physikalisches Modell, dass auf einem Raster beruht \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Chemicals, Runoff and Erosion from Agricultural Management Systems} (CREAMS) & 
   physikalisch & feldgroßes EZG, 40--400 ha & täglich oder ereignisbezogen &  Grabenerosion und \mbox{-deposition} & verwendet statt eines Rasters ein Diskretisierungsverfahren, mit dem homogene Elemente festgelegt werden \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Limburg Soil Erosion Model} (LISEM) & 
   physikalisch & Hang\slash kleines EZG & ereignisbezogen & simuliert keine Erosionstypen sondern den Abtrag durch Wasseransammlungen & räumliche Verteilung des Outputs wird als Karte ausgegeben \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Productivity, Erosion and Runoff, Functions to Evaluate Conservation Techniques} (PERFECT) & 
   physikalisch & blablabla & blablabla & blablabla & blablabla \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Universal Soil Loss Equation} (USLE) & 
   empirisch & Hang\slash kleine landwirtschaftliche EZG & jährlicher Mittelwert & Rillen- und Flächenerosion & beruht auf langjährigen Messreihen aus den USA, Basis für viele weitere Modelle \\
   \addlinespace
   \foreignlanguage{english}{Water Erosion Prediction Project} (WEPP) & 
   physikalisch & Module für Hang\slash EZG & ereignisbezogen, monatlich & Flächen-, Rillen-, Grabenerosion & verschiedene Version auch für Wald- und Straßenbau\\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```