# The caption is not spanning the entire width of the table

Tags: tables, captions, multicolumn

This is my latex code for a table. **The caption is not spanning the entire width of the table.** Can anyone help me fix it?

```
\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\caption{xxx}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
\toprule[1.7pt]
& & &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Cccccccccc Ccccccccc} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Cccccccccc Ccccccccc} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-11} 
& &A &\multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 1000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 1000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 1000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 1000} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
& &Ssssssss size &N = 1000&N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 \\
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{XXX} & &a &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} \\
& &a &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} \\
\toprule
\multirow{10}{*}{YYY} &\multirow{2}{*}{aaaa} &aaaa &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-11}
&\multirow{4}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\toprule
\multirow{10}{*}{ZZZ} &\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-11}
&\multirow{4}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\bottomrule[1.7pt]
\end{tabular}
\caption*{\textit{\scriptsize aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The caption is not spanning the entire width of the table.

Comment: Why you need two captions?

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with your table isn't that the caption isn't centered relative to the `tabular` material. Rather, the main problem is that the `tabular` material is simply much wider than `\textwidth`.

I suggest you typeset the table in landscape mode. One way of achieving this is by employing a `sidewaystable` environment (provided by the [rotating](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package) instead of a `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,rotating}

% Cf. Marcel Krüger's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694046/5001 
\usepackage{floatpag,pdflscape}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rotateview}{\global\@namedef{\number\@currbox @float}{\PLS@AddRotate{90}%
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{\PLS@RemoveRotate}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\rotateview

\centering
\caption{xxx}

\scriptsize % you should also try '\footnotesize' and '\small'
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{11}{c} @{}} % table has 11 columns, not 12
\toprule% [1.7pt] % 1.7pt -- really?
& & &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Cccccccccc Ccccccccc} 
    &\multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Cccccccccc Ccccccccc} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-7} \cmidrule(l){8-11} 
& &A &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$N = 1000$} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$N = 1000$} 
     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$N = 1000$} &\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$N = 1000$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11}
& &Ssssssss size 
     &$N = 1000$ &$N = 1000$ &$N = 1000$ &$N = 1000$ 
     &$N = 1000$ &$N = 1000$ &$N = 1000$ &$N = 1000$ \\
     
\midrule %% \toprule

\multirow{2}{*}{XXX} & &a &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{0.0000} \\
& &a &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{0.0000} \\
  
\midrule %%\toprule
\multirow{10}{*}{YYY} % I'd run '\multirow{11}{*}{YYY}'
&\multirow{2}{*}{aaaa} &aaaa &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
&\multirow{4}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
%\cmidrule(l){2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\

\midrule %% \toprule
\multirow{10}{*}{ZZZ} % I'd run '\multirow{11}{*}{ZZZ}'
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
&\multirow{4}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
\bottomrule% [1.7pt] % 1.7pt -- really?

\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

- You not provide any information about your document page layout
- In the case, when you use `a4paper` and have `25mm` margins, than the following MWE can solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{seqsplit}   % <---


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering
\caption{xxx}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{11}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
& & &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Cccccccccc Ccccccccc} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Cccccccccc Ccccccccc} \\
    \cmidrule{4-7} \cmidrule{8-11}
& &A &\multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 1000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 1000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 1000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{N = 1000} \\
\cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{10-11}
& & Ssssssss size &N = 1000&N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 &N = 1000 \\
    \midrule[0.4pt]
\multirow{2}{*}{XXX} & &a &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} \\
& &a &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{0.0000} \\
    \midrule[0.4pt]
\multirow{10}{*}{YYY} &\multirow{2}{*}{aaaa} &aaaa &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
&\multirow{4}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
    \midrule[0.4pt]
\multirow{10}{*}{ZZZ} &\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
&\multirow{4}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
&\multirow{2}{*}{a} &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
& &a &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 &0.0000 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption*{\textit{\seqsplit{ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The neat thing about using a `tabular*` environment and setting `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` is that you no longer need the `@{}` particles to adjust padding, and you don't need to apply any padding adjustments to the `\cmidrule` directives either. Just drop the `l{-1pt}` and `r{-1pt}` particles in the arguments of `\cmidrule`. For instance, try `\cmidrule{4-7}` instead of `\cmidrule(l{-1pt}r{-1pt}){4-7}`. A separate issue: the OP's code uses `\toprule` for some of the interior rules; I think it would be better to use `\midrule` in those instances. Finally, the table has 11 columns, not 12.

Comment: @Mico, you are right! Thank you very much for exhaustive comment! Corrected now (I to blindly follows to OP code, sorry for this).