# Fit wide table and resize page in Latex

Tags: tables, margins, landscape

I have this table:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
  \centering
   \caption{Effects of air pollution in ER admissions by age groups in Mexicali}
   \label{tab:app_age_zinb_mx}
   

  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{


        \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
        
    \toprule
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{ER Admissions}} \\[.8ex]

& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{PM$_{2.5}$ (75+)}} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{NO$_{2}$ (75+)}} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{PM$_{2.5}$ (0-5)}} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{NO$_{2}$ (0-5)}}\\ [.8ex]
       &Lag=1 & Lag=2 & Lag=3 & Lag=1 & Lag=2 & Lag=3 &Lag=1 & Lag=2 & Lag=3 & Lag=1 & Lag=2 & Lag=3 \\ [.8ex]
        & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) &(11) & (12)\\ \midrule
        & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Negative binomial}} \\ [.8ex]
Constant & -1.389$^{***}$ & -1.221$^{***}$ & -1.285$^{***}$ &  -1.386$^{***}$& -1.398$^{***}$ & -1.313$^{***}$ &  0.091 &  0.007 &  0.348 & -0.310$^{***}$ & -0.354$^{***}$ & -0.400$^{***}$ \\ 
   & ( 0.345) & ( 0.347) & ( 0.361) & (  0.332) & ( 0.343) & ( 0.318) & ( 0.188) & ( 0.189) & ( 0.193) & ( 0.157) & ( 0.158) & ( 0.162) \\ 
  Pollutant &  0.016 &  0.042 &  0.036 &   0.014 &  0.026 &  0.028 &  0.001 & -0.005 & -0.006 &  0.012 &  0.010 &  0.008 \\ 
   & ( 0.034) & ( 0.026) & ( 0.027) & (  0.026) & ( 0.020) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.010) & ( 0.008) & ( 0.008) \\ 
  Pollutant lag &  0.035 & -0.008 &  0.003 &   0.036 &  0.024 &  0.017 & -0.007 &  0.005 &  0.005 &  0.017$^{**}$ &  0.023$^{***}$ &  0.027$^{***}$ \\ 
   & ( 0.034) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.028) & (  0.030) & ( 0.023) & ( 0.026) & ( 0.013) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.010) & ( 0.008) & ( 0.008) \\ 
  Trend &  0.151 &  0.206 &  0.204 &   0.124 &  0.162 &  0.147 &  0.440$^{***}$ &  0.435$^{***}$ &  0.450$^{***}$ &  0.349$^{***}$ &  0.345$^{***}$ &  0.360$^{***}$ \\ 
   & ( 0.221) & ( 0.219) & ( 0.219) & (  0.190) & ( 0.198) & ( 0.196) & ( 0.118) & ( 0.118) & ( 0.119) & ( 0.099) & ( 0.098) & ( 0.098) \\[.8ex] 
   & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Zero-inflated}} \\ [.8ex]
  Constant & -1.138 & -1.125 & -1.110 &  -0.400 & -0.544 & -0.411 & -0.488 & -0.545 & -0.727 &  0.244 &  0.316 &  0.387 \\ 
   & ( 0.740) & ( 0.736) & ( 0.757) & (  0.707) & ( 0.736) & ( 0.651) & ( 0.469) & ( 0.476) & ( 0.502) & ( 0.324) & ( 0.329) & ( 0.337) \\ 
  Pollutant &  0.091 &  0.108$^{**}$ &  0.103$^{**}$ &   0.046 &  0.027 &  0.021 &  0.039 &  0.036 &  0.027 &  0.002 & -0.006 & -0.002 \\ 
   & ( 0.072) & ( 0.056) & ( 0.058) & (  0.055) & ( 0.041) & ( 0.049) & ( 0.031) & ( 0.030) & ( 0.030) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.021) & ( 0.021) \\ 
  Pollutant lag &  0.008 & -0.013 & -0.009 &  -0.011 &  0.018 &  0.016 & -0.020 & -0.013 &  0.011 & -0.043$^{**}$ & -0.040$^{**}$ & -0.051$^{***}$ \\ 
   & ( 0.069) & ( 0.048) & ( 0.057) & (  0.065) & ( 0.048) & ( 0.053) & ( 0.032) & ( 0.031) & ( 0.032) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.021) & ( 0.021) \\ 
  Trend & -0.390 & -0.345 & -0.340 &  -0.353 & -0.312 & -0.329 & -0.851$^{***}$ & -0.854$^{***}$ & -0.856$^{***}$ & -0.725$^{***}$ & -0.731$^{***}$ & -0.740$^{***}$ \\ 
   & ( 0.417) & ( 0.412) & ( 0.413) & (  0.364) & ( 0.379) & ( 0.373) & ( 0.268) & ( 0.269) & ( 0.272) & ( 0.225) & ( 0.225) & ( 0.227) \\ \midrule 
   N observations & 433 & 433 & 433 & 433 & 433 & 433 & 1380 & 1380 & 1380 & 1380 & 1380 & 1380 \\
  Dispersion parameter &  555514.507 & 1165112.235 &  455913.539 &   89734.880 &  227164.613 &  150688.597 &       2.494 &       2.462 &       2.449 &       2.907 &       3.026 &       3.044 \\ 
  AIC &    1689.249 &    1685.436 &    1685.043 &    1883.727 &    1884.437 &    1885.301 &    3349.339 &    3348.409 &    3341.986 &    3652.969 &    3643.089 &    3625.998 \\ 
  BIC &    1735.506 &    1731.686 &    1731.285 &    1930.989 &    1931.693 &    1932.550 &    3395.596 &    3394.659 &    3388.228 &    3700.231 &    3690.345 &    3673.247 \\ 
  TIC &    1687.482 &    1682.223 &    1681.999 &    1882.537 &    1882.563 &    1884.029 &    3348.384 &    3347.167 &    3341.139 &    3651.995 &    3642.318 &    3625.142 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
   
   
   
 \end{table}
   \end{landscape}
```

The problem is that the page is too wide and doesn't fit with the rest of the pages.

I want it to fit like the table I'm attaching as an image; how can I do that?[image]

Comment: Don't scale elements which contain text. Choose an appropriate font size instead.

Comment: Isn't it up to your pdf viewer and/or your settings in the viewer, how a rotated page is displayed?

Comment: if I use {sidewaystable} and I rotate, I get a wider page than the size of all the document.

Comment: Making it smaller, with \tiny doesn't make it better than using scalebox

Comment: Using `\tiny` will give you appropriately shaped letters instead of just scaling down letters, which are designed to be read at normal size. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425454/36296 for more details.

Comment: The tiny letters just make the table very small and not clear to read, that I'm trying to avoid to give the reader more space by turning it to landscape format

Comment: Turning the table sideways is good, using `\scalebox{0.7}{...}` is not good.

Comment: Either way, using it doesn't help with the size of the page; see edited code. I still have the same problem with the size of page

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ, how wide and tall the text block is (or, equivalently, how wide the margins are, and what the main document font size is.

Comment: I'm using this template https://www.overleaf.com/project/64afceb5e4e56f314795f5d0

Comment: @Lilia - I get the message "Restricted, sorry you don’t have permission to load this page." when I click on the link you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My main piece of advice is to align the numbers in the 12 data columns on their decimal markers. And, do provide a bit more visual structure on the header material. Oh, and don't abuse **bold-facing**.

Observe that as long as the margins aren't excessively wide, one can get by without reducing the font size, either manually or via the `\resizebox` sledgehammer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set as appropriate
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{mhchem}   % for '\ce'  macro
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % to align numbers on their decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

% Cf. Marcel Krüger's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694046/5001 
\usepackage{floatpag,pdflscape}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rotateview}{\global\@namedef{\number\@currbox @float}{\PLS@AddRotate{90}%
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{\PLS@RemoveRotate}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{sidewaystable}
\rotateview

\caption{Effects of air pollution on ER admissions, by age groups in Mexicali}
\label{tab:app_age_zinb_mx}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace padding

\bigskip
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{12}{d{2.6}} }

\toprule
& \multicolumn{12}{c}{ER Admissions} \\
\cmidrule{2-13}

& \multicolumn{3}{c}{PM\textsubscript{2.5} (75+)}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\ce{NO2}   (75+)}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{PM\textsubscript{2.5} (0--5)}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\ce{NO2}   (0--5)} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
& \mc{Lag=1} & \mc{Lag=2} & \mc{Lag=3} & \mc{Lag=1} & \mc{Lag=2} & \mc{Lag=3}
& \mc{Lag=1} & \mc{Lag=2} & \mc{Lag=3} & \mc{Lag=1} & \mc{Lag=2} & \mc{Lag=3} \\
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)}  & \mc{(5)}  & \mc{(6)}
& \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)} & \mc{(9)} & \mc{(10)} & \mc{(11)} & \mc{(12)} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{13}{l}{\bfseries Negative binomial} \\
\addlinespace
Constant & -1.389^{***} & -1.221^{***} & -1.285^{***} &  -1.386^{***}& -1.398^{***} & -1.313^{***} &  0.091 &  0.007 &  0.348 & -0.310^{***} & -0.354^{***} & -0.400^{***} \\
   & ( 0.345) & ( 0.347) & ( 0.361) & (  0.332) & ( 0.343) & ( 0.318) & ( 0.188) & ( 0.189) & ( 0.193) & ( 0.157) & ( 0.158) & ( 0.162) \\
  Pollutant &  0.016 &  0.042 &  0.036 &   0.014 &  0.026 &  0.028 &  0.001 & -0.005 & -0.006 &  0.012 &  0.010 &  0.008 \\
   & ( 0.034) & ( 0.026) & ( 0.027) & (  0.026) & ( 0.020) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.010) & ( 0.008) & ( 0.008) \\
  Pollutant, lagged &  0.035 & -0.008 &  0.003 &   0.036 &  0.024 &  0.017 & -0.007 &  0.005 &  0.005 &  0.017^{**} &  0.023^{***} &  0.027^{***} \\
   & ( 0.034) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.028) & (  0.030) & ( 0.023) & ( 0.026) & ( 0.013) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.010) & ( 0.008) & ( 0.008) \\
  Trend &  0.151 &  0.206 &  0.204 &   0.124 &  0.162 &  0.147 &  0.440^{***} &  0.435^{***} &  0.450^{***} &  0.349^{***} &  0.345^{***} &  0.360^{***} \\
   & ( 0.221) & ( 0.219) & ( 0.219) & (  0.190) & ( 0.198) & ( 0.196) & ( 0.118) & ( 0.118) & ( 0.119) & ( 0.099) & ( 0.098) & ( 0.098) \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{13}{l}{\bfseries Zero-inflated} \\
\addlinespace
  Constant & -1.138 & -1.125 & -1.110 &  -0.400 & -0.544 & -0.411 & -0.488 & -0.545 & -0.727 &  0.244 &  0.316 &  0.387 \\
   & ( 0.740) & ( 0.736) & ( 0.757) & (  0.707) & ( 0.736) & ( 0.651) & ( 0.469) & ( 0.476) & ( 0.502) & ( 0.324) & ( 0.329) & ( 0.337) \\
  Pollutant &  0.091 &  0.108^{**} &  0.103^{**} &   0.046 &  0.027 &  0.021 &  0.039 &  0.036 &  0.027 &  0.002 & -0.006 & -0.002 \\
   & ( 0.072) & ( 0.056) & ( 0.058) & (  0.055) & ( 0.041) & ( 0.049) & ( 0.031) & ( 0.030) & ( 0.030) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.021) & ( 0.021) \\
  Pollutant, lagged &  0.008 & -0.013 & -0.009 &  -0.011 &  0.018 &  0.016 & -0.020 & -0.013 &  0.011 & -0.043^{**} & -0.040^{**} & -0.051^{***} \\
   & ( 0.069) & ( 0.048) & ( 0.057) & (  0.065) & ( 0.048) & ( 0.053) & ( 0.032) & ( 0.031) & ( 0.032) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.021) & ( 0.021) \\
  Trend & -0.390 & -0.345 & -0.340 &  -0.353 & -0.312 & -0.329 & -0.851^{***} & -0.854^{***} & -0.856^{***} & -0.725^{***} & -0.731^{***} & -0.740^{***} \\
   & ( 0.417) & ( 0.412) & ( 0.413) & (  0.364) & ( 0.379) & ( 0.373) & ( 0.268) & ( 0.269) & ( 0.272) & ( 0.225) & ( 0.225) & ( 0.227) \\
\midrule
No.\ of obs. & \mc{433} & \mc{433} & \mc{433} & \mc{433} & \mc{433} & \mc{433} & \mc{1380} & \mc{1380} & \mc{1380} & \mc{1380} & \mc{1380} & \mc{1380} \\
Disp.\ param. & \mc{555514.507} & \mc{1165112.235} & \mc{455913.539} & \mc{89734.880} & \mc{227164.613} & \mc{150688.597} & \mc{2.494} & \mc{2.462} & \mc{2.449} & \mc{ 2.907} & \mc{3.026} & \mc{3.044} \\
AIC & \mc{1689.249} & \mc{1685.436} & \mc{1685.043} & \mc{1883.727} & \mc{1884.437} & \mc{1885.301} & \mc{3349.339} & \mc{3348.409} & \mc{ 3341.986} & \mc{3652.969} & \mc{3643.089} & \mc{3625.998} \\
BIC & \mc{1735.506} & \mc{1731.686} & \mc{1731.285} & \mc{1930.989} & \mc{1931.693} & \mc{1932.550} & \mc{3395.596} & \mc{3394.659} & \mc{ 3388.228} & \mc{3700.231} & \mc{3690.345} & \mc{3673.247} \\
TIC & \mc{1687.482} & \mc{1682.223} & \mc{1681.999} & \mc{1882.537} & \mc{1882.563} & \mc{1884.029} & \mc{3348.384} & \mc{3347.167} & \mc{ 3341.139} & \mc{3651.995} & \mc{3642.318} & \mc{3625.142} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the table is sideways which makes it hard to read, that's why I'm trying to put it into landscape for easy access to it.

Comment: @Lilia - I've added some code that should address your objection that the table was "hard to read".

Comment: Thank you, here is the template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-sussex-thesis-template-unofficial/wwfbtzrcpdyz

And the code you provided, is it that I'm missing something? The render is vertical, I want it to have it horizontal.

Comment: @Lilia - You asked, "Is it that I'm missing something?" Yes. Please reload the page and only then copy and paste the code into your editor.

Answer (score 3):

See if the following suggestion gives what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
  \centering
   \caption{Effects of air pollution in ER admissions by age groups in Mexicali}
   \label{tab:app_age_zinb_mx}

\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} >{\raggedright}m{6.6em} cccccccccccc}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{ER Admissions}} \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{PM$_{2.5}$ (75+)}} 
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{NO$_{2}$ (75+)}} 
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{PM$_{2.5}$ (0-5)}} 
                &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{NO$_{2}$ (0-5)}}\\ [.8ex]
    &Lag=1 & Lag=2 & Lag=3 & Lag=1 & Lag=2 & Lag=3 &Lag=1 & Lag=2 & Lag=3 & Lag=1 & Lag=2 & Lag=3 \\ [.8ex]
    & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) &(11) & (12)\\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Negative binomial}} \\ [.8ex]
Constant 
    & -1.389$^{***}$ & -1.221$^{***}$ & -1.285$^{***}$ &  -1.386$^{***}$& -1.398$^{***}$ & -1.313$^{***}$ &  0.091 &  0.007 &  0.348 & -0.310$^{***}$ & -0.354$^{***}$ & -0.400$^{***}$ \\
    & ( 0.345) & ( 0.347) & ( 0.361) & (  0.332) & ( 0.343) & ( 0.318) & ( 0.188) & ( 0.189) & ( 0.193) & ( 0.157) & ( 0.158) & ( 0.162) \\
Pollutant 
    &  0.016 &  0.042 &  0.036 &   0.014 &  0.026 &  0.028 &  0.001 & -0.005 & -0.006 &  0.012 &  0.010 &  0.008 \\
   & ( 0.034) & ( 0.026) & ( 0.027) & (  0.026) & ( 0.020) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.010) & ( 0.008) & ( 0.008) \\
Pollutant lag 
    &  0.035 & -0.008 &  0.003 &   0.036 &  0.024 &  0.017 & -0.007 &  0.005 &  0.005 &  0.017$^{**}$ &  0.023$^{***}$ &  0.027$^{***}$ \\
    & ( 0.034) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.028) & (  0.030) & ( 0.023) & ( 0.026) & ( 0.013) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.012) & ( 0.010) & ( 0.008) & ( 0.008) \\
Trend 
    &  0.151 &  0.206 &  0.204 &   0.124 &  0.162 &  0.147 &  0.440$^{***}$ &  0.435$^{***}$ &  0.450$^{***}$ &  0.349$^{***}$ &  0.345$^{***}$ &  0.360$^{***}$ \\
    & ( 0.221) & ( 0.219) & ( 0.219) & (  0.190) & ( 0.198) & ( 0.196) & ( 0.118) & ( 0.118) & ( 0.119) & ( 0.099) & ( 0.098) & ( 0.098) \\[.8ex]
    & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Zero-inflated}} \\ [.8ex]
Constant & -1.138 & -1.125 & -1.110 &  -0.400 & -0.544 & -0.411 & -0.488 & -0.545 & -0.727 &  0.244 &  0.316 &  0.387 \\
   & ( 0.740) & ( 0.736) & ( 0.757) & (  0.707) & ( 0.736) & ( 0.651) & ( 0.469) & ( 0.476) & ( 0.502) & ( 0.324) & ( 0.329) & ( 0.337) \\
Pollutant 
    &  0.091 &  0.108$^{**}$ &  0.103$^{**}$ &   0.046 &  0.027 &  0.021 &  0.039 &  0.036 &  0.027 &  0.002 & -0.006 & -0.002 \\
    & ( 0.072) & ( 0.056) & ( 0.058) & (  0.055) & ( 0.041) & ( 0.049) & ( 0.031) & ( 0.030) & ( 0.030) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.021) & ( 0.021) \\
Pollutant lag &  0.008 & -0.013 & -0.009 &  -0.011 &  0.018 &  0.016 & -0.020 & -0.013 &  0.011 & -0.043$^{**}$ & -0.040$^{**}$ & -0.051$^{***}$ \\
    & ( 0.069) & ( 0.048) & ( 0.057) & (  0.065) & ( 0.048) & ( 0.053) & ( 0.032) & ( 0.031) & ( 0.032) & ( 0.024) & ( 0.021) & ( 0.021) \\
Trend 
    & -0.390 & -0.345 & -0.340 &  -0.353 & -0.312 & -0.329 & -0.851$^{***}$ & -0.854$^{***}$ & -0.856$^{***}$ & -0.725$^{***}$ & -0.731$^{***}$ & -0.740$^{***}$ \\
   & ( 0.417) & ( 0.412) & ( 0.413) & (  0.364) & ( 0.379) & ( 0.373) & ( 0.268) & ( 0.269) & ( 0.272) & ( 0.225) & ( 0.225) & ( 0.227) \\ \midrule
N observations 
    & 433 & 433 & 433 & 433 & 433 & 433 & 1380 & 1380 & 1380 & 1380 & 1380 & 1380 \\
Dispersion parameter &  555514.507 & 1165112.235 &  455913.539 &   89734.880 &  227164.613 &  150688.597 &       2.494 &       2.462 &       2.449 &       2.907 &       3.026 &       3.044 \\
AIC &    1689.249 &    1685.436 &    1685.043 &    1883.727 &    1884.437 &    1885.301 &    3349.339 &    3348.409 &    3341.986 &    3652.969 &    3643.089 &    3625.998 \\
BIC &    1735.506 &    1731.686 &    1731.285 &    1930.989 &    1931.693 &    1932.550 &    3395.596 &    3394.659 &    3388.228 &    3700.231 &    3690.345 &    3673.247 \\
TIC &    1687.482 &    1682.223 &    1681.999 &    1882.537 &    1882.563 &    1884.029 &    3348.384 &    3347.167 &    3341.139 &    3651.995 &    3642.318 &    3625.142 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I didn't interfere in table design, however i woul'd rethinking about its design. Use of the `siunitx` and `threeparttable` would gives nicer looking table.