# Overfull \hbox (242.24484pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 18--59

Tags: positioning

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Sports Nutrition-Related Behavior, Overall Dietary Intake, and Physical Activity}
For the sports nutrition global score, we found weak evidence $\left(\mathrm{BF}_{\text {incl }}=2.75\right)$ for the interaction effect between group and measurement time point (FUEL: $1.7 \pm 0.5$ at week 0 and $2.2 \pm 0.4$ at week $17 ;$ CON: $1.9 \pm 0.4$ at week 0 and $2.0 \pm 0.4$ at week 17 ). Similarly, we found weak support for an interaction effect between group and measurement time point for total energy intake, and carbohydrates (g/day and $\mathrm{g} / \mathrm{kg} /$ day), protein (g/day and $\mathrm{g} / \mathrm{kg} /$ day), and fat (E\%) intake (Table 4 ).

Table 4. Dietary characteristics for the intervention (FUEL) and control (CON) group.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multirow[b]{2}{*}{Dietary Intake} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{FUEL} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$\mathrm{CON}$} & \multirow[b]{2}{*}{$\mathbf{B F}_{\text {incl }}$} \\
\hline
 & Week 0 & Week 17 & \begin{tabular}{c}
within Group \\
Difference \\
\end{tabular} & Week 0 & Week 17 & \begin{tabular}{c}
within Group \\
Difference \\
\end{tabular} &  \\
\hline
Energy intake (kcal/day) & $2588 \pm 528$ & $2726 \pm 547$ & $138 \pm 453$ & $2455 \pm 482$ & $2300 \pm 449$ & $-155 \pm 396$ & 1.03 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{}\begin{tabular}{l}
Carbohydrates (g/day) \\
Carbohydrates (g/kg/day) \\
Carbohydrates (E\%) \\
\end{tabular} & $290 \pm 68$ & $326 \pm 88$ & $36 \pm 74$ & $285 \pm 65$ & $280 \pm 74$ & $-6 \pm 62$ & 1.09 \\
\hline
 & $4.8 \pm 1.0$ & $5.5 \pm 1.4$ & $0.6 \pm 1.3$ & $4.8 \pm 1.0$ & $4.7 \pm 1.2$ & $-0.1 \pm 1.0$ & 1.04 \\
\hline
 & $47 \pm 8$ & $50 \pm 8$ & $2.7 \pm 9.4$ & $49 \pm 5$ & $51 \pm 6$ & $2.2 \pm 5.4$ & 0.38 \\
\hline
Dietary fibers (g/day) & $37.5 \pm 12.5$ & $36.7 \pm 12.7$ & $-1 \pm 10$ & $36 \pm 9$ & $37 \pm 15$ & $1 \pm 12$ & 0.37 \\
\hline
Dietary fibers (g/1000 kcal) & $14.4 \pm 3.8$ & $13.3 \pm 3.1$ & $-1.1 \pm 3.2$ & $14.9 \pm 3.6$ & $15.9 \pm 5.2$ & $1.0 \pm 4.7$ & 0.88 \\
\hline
Protein (g/day) & $107 \pm 30$ & $115 \pm 31$ & $8 \pm 22$ & $95 \pm 19$ & $88 \pm 24$ & $-7 \pm 17$ & 1.06 \\
\hline
Protein (g/kg/day) & $1.8 \pm 0.5$ & $1.9 \pm 0.5$ & $0.1 \pm 0.4$ & $1.6 \pm 0.3$ & $1.5 \pm 0.4$ & $-0.1 \pm 0.3$ & 1.12 \\
\hline
Protein (E\%) & $17 \pm 4$ & $18 \pm 4$ & $3 \pm 3$ & $17 \pm 4$ & $16 \pm 4$ & $-1 \pm 2$ & 0.42 \\
\hline
Fat (g/day) & $106 \pm 35$ & $96 \pm 26$ & $-10 \pm 34$ & $97 \pm 24$ & $88 \pm 23$ & $-9 \pm 23$ & 0.36 \\
\hline
Fat (g/kg/day) & $1.8 \pm 0.6$ & $1.6 \pm 0.4$ & $-0.2 \pm 0.6$ & $1.6 \pm 0.3$ & $1.4 \pm 0.4$ & $-0.2 \pm 0.4$ & 0.38 \\
\hline
Fat $(\mathrm{E} \%)$ & $37 \pm 9$ & $32 \pm 6$ & $-5 \pm 9$ & $35 \pm 5$ & $34 \pm 7$ & $-1 \pm 7$ & 1.43 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your tabular is much too wide. [You have to decide, how to make it smaller and/or rotate it.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/277964)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What is your question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - I would guess it's how to deal with the fact that the `tabular` environment's width is more more than 3 inches greater than the width of the text block. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not surprising that the table exceeds the width of the text block, given by the parameter `\textwidth`, by far, because it has a wide header column and 7 generous data columns. The only hope I see is to render the table in landscape mode instead of in portrait mode. This may be done with the help of the `rotating` package and its `sidewaystable` environment.

[image]

[image]

Observe that I would also recommend getting rid of all vertical
lines in a table and using fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % not needed in this example
%\usepackage{stmaryrd} % not needed in this example

%% new code:
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % centered & automatic math mode

% Cf. Marcel Krüger's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694046/5001 
\usepackage{floatpag,pdflscape}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rotateview}{\global\@namedef{\number\@currbox @float}{\PLS@AddRotate{90}%
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{\PLS@RemoveRotate}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection{Sports Nutrition-Related Behavior, Overall 
Dietary Intake, and Physical Activity}

For the sports nutrition global score, we found weak evidence    
$(\mathrm{BF}_{\text {incl}}=2.75)$ for the interaction effect 
between group and measurement time point (FUEL: $1.7\pm0.5$ 
at week~0 and $2.2\pm0.4$ at week~$17$;  CON: $1.9\pm0.4$ at 
week~0 and $2.0\pm0.4$ at week~17). Similarly, we found weak 
support for an interaction effect between group and measurement 
time point for total energy intake, and carbohydrates (g/day 
and g/kg/day), protein (g/day and g/kg/day), and fat (E\%) 
intake (Table \ref{tab:dietary}).

\setcounter{table}{3}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\rotateview

\caption{Dietary characteristics for the intervention (FUEL) and control (CON) group.} \label{tab:dietary}

\smallskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{C} }
\toprule
Dietary Intake & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{FUEL} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{CON} & 
\mathrm{B F}_{\textrm{incl}} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7}
& \text{Week 0} & \text{Week 17} & 
\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Within group \\difference \end{tabular} 
& \text{Week 0} & \text{Week 17} & 
\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Within group \\difference \end{tabular} &  \\
\midrule
Energy intake (kcal/day) & 2588\pm528 & 2726\pm547 & 138\pm453 & 2455\pm482 & 2300\pm449 & -155\pm396 & 1.03 \\
\addlinespace
Carbohydrates (g/day) & 290\pm68 & 326\pm88 & 36\pm74 & 285\pm65 & 280\pm74 & -6\pm62 & 1.09\\
Carbohydrates (g/kg/day) & 4.8\pm1.0 & 5.5\pm1.4 & 0.6\pm1.3 & 4.8\pm1.0 & 4.7\pm1.2 & -0.1\pm1.0 & 1.04\\
Carbohydrates (E\%) & 47\pm8 & 50\pm8 & 2.7\pm9.4 & 49\pm5 & 51\pm6 & 2.2\pm5.4 & 0.38\\
\addlinespace
Dietary fibers (g/day) & 37.5\pm12.5 & 36.7\pm12.7 & -1\pm10 & 36\pm9 & 37\pm15 & 1\pm12 & 0.37 \\
Dietary fibers (g/1000 kcal) & 14.4\pm3.8 & 13.3\pm3.1 & -1.1\pm3.2 & 14.9\pm3.6 & 15.9\pm5.2 & 1.0\pm4.7 & 0.88 \\
Protein (g/day) & 107\pm30 & 115\pm31 & 8\pm22 & 95\pm19 & 88\pm24 & -7\pm17 & 1.06 \\
Protein (g/kg/day) & 1.8\pm0.5 & 1.9\pm0.5 & 0.1\pm0.4 & 1.6\pm0.3 & 1.5\pm0.4 & -0.1\pm0.3 & 1.12 \\
Protein (E\%) & 17\pm4 & 18\pm4 & 3\pm3 & 17\pm4 & 16\pm4 & -1\pm2 & 0.42 \\
Fat (g/day) & 106\pm35 & 96\pm26 & -10\pm34 & 97\pm24 & 88\pm23 & -9\pm23 & 0.36 \\
Fat (g/kg/day) & 1.8\pm0.6 & 1.6\pm0.4 & -0.2\pm0.6 & 1.6\pm0.3 & 1.4\pm0.4 & -0.2\pm0.4 & 0.38 \\
Fat (E \%) & 37\pm9 & 32\pm6 & -5\pm9 & 35\pm5 & 34\pm7 & -1\pm7 & 1.43 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.